# Change the border color of a label on user selection

Tags: c#, event-handling

I want to change the border color of a label when the user selects the color he wants to. I know that the paint event of a label can change the border color. I just want this code:

```
private void label1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, label1.DisplayRectangle, Color.Blue, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
}
```

to work on:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
      {
           //apply red color
      }
}
```

the selected index (color the user wants) of a combo box to apply. I just don't know how to.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Color selectedColor;

private void label1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, label1.DisplayRectangle, selectedColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        selectedColor = Color.Red;         
    }
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        selectColor = Color.Blue;
    }
    label1.Invalidate();
    label1.Update();
}
```

Comment: Hello I have a problem the color red stays even if the user selects another color. How do I remove the paint color and then redraw another color?

Comment: Okay ill try just a minute. Sorry for bothering again.

Comment: The color stays on the border. :(

Comment: Try it with the call to the base method? Please let me know if it works :)

Comment: Sorry but how do I do that? I'm just new in c#.

Comment: Cant believe I missed that! Anyways we got there in the end